# PlayFramework - How to upload file/image

Tags: java, image, playframework, image-uploading

I want to upload file/image on my website. 
Actually i can upload my file but sometimes i've error on my page and i think it's not the good way to do this.

My code :

```
private String uploadImage()
{
    String result = f.validate("avatar");
    if(result.isEmpty())
        return "none";
    Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart<File> file = body.getFile("avatar");

    if(file == null)
        return "File is empty or not exist.";

    String filename = file.getFilename();

    /* Debug file file*/
    Logger.debug("nameFile " + file.getFilename());
    Logger.debug("contentFile " + file.getContentType());
    /* End debug*/

    File f = file.getFile();

    /* Debug file f*/
    String name = f.getName();
    long totalSpace = f.getTotalSpace();
    Logger.debug("nameF " + name);
    Logger.debug("sizeF " + totalSpace);
    /* End debug*/

    try {
        /* File user is not f file variable*/
        File fileUser = getFileUser(filename);
        Try.of(fileUser::delete);

        /* Use of org.apache.commons.io*/
        FileUtils.moveFile(f, getFileUser(filename));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}

private File getFileUser(String fileName)
{
    return new File("public/upload/avatars",
                     user.getId().toString() + "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName));
}

private boolean fileIsPicture(File f)
{
    String mimetype = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f);
    String type = mimetype.split("/")[0];
    return (type.equals("image"));
}
```

Error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'C:\Users\Alexis\AppData\Local\Temp\playtemp1188878075698565675\multipartBody8627595002998720963asTemporaryFile' does not exist
```

But i've a debug with some informations (Why 2 times debug?):

```
[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
[info] application - avatar  null
[debug] application - nameFile KwizzyPicture.jpg
[debug] application - contentFile image/jpeg
[debug] application - nameF multipartBody1959853090277810547asTemporaryFile
[debug] application - sizeF 763679993856
[info] application - avatar  null
[debug] application - nameFile KwizzyPicture.jpg
[debug] application - contentFile image/jpeg
[debug] application - nameF multipartBody1959853090277810547asTemporaryFile
[debug] application - sizeF 0
```

[Full code here](https://gist.github.com/Kwizzy-DEV/7c40ec62d7b371972e7c45f4690f7b7e)

Thank you for your help ! 
I'm french so sorry for mistakes.

Comment: Paste the complete stack trace where the FileNoutFoundException is thrown.

Comment: Okay wait few minutes i come back

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Kwizzy-DEV/7c40ec62d7b371972e7c45f4690f7b7e

Comment: Nobody can help me ?

Comment: look at my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569339/scala-play-framework-image-upload-with-angular-ng-file-upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use FileInputStream and FileOutptStream classes

```
  Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart<File> file = body.getFile("avatar");

 FileInputStream in = null;
  FileOutputStream out = null;
  try {
     in = new FileInputStream(file);
     //enter the file location in server
     out = new FileOutputStream("output.jpeg");

     int c;
     while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(c);
     }
  }finally {
     if (in != null) {
        in.close();
     }
     if (out != null) {
        out.close();
     }
  }
```

Comment: I've use Spring FileCopy Util ;) But i think your anwser work too